# Wkhtmltopdf redirect to login page in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, wkhtmltopdf, sonata-admin

I'm using wkhtmltopdf to generate a pdf report in my application,but when the pdf is generated,i got the login page in the pdf.

this is my Action:

```
public function exportPdfAction($id = 0)
{
    $em = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
    $id = $this->get('request')->get($this->admin->getIdParameter());
    $object = $this->admin->getObject($id);


    if (!$object) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException(sprintf('unable to find the object with id : %s', $id));
    }

    if (false === $this->admin->isGranted('VIEW', $object)) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException();
    }

    $pageUrl = $this->generateUrl('admin_rh_leave_conge_show', array('id'=>$id), true); // use absolute path!

     return new Response(
        $this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->getOutput($pageUrl),
        200,
        array(
            'Content-Type'          => 'application/pdf',
            'Content-Disposition'   => 'attachment; filename="Fiche_conge.pdf"'

        )
    );   
}
```

how can i resolve the problem ?

Comment: You will probably have to put a little more details if you want some helpful answers.

Comment: so i will update my question

Comment: my question is updated

Comment: Seems like this might be an issue with the bundle: https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpSnappyBundle/issues/26

Comment: then,we can't generated a pdf from a secure route ?

Comment: Well, not as it currently stands but you can probably fork the project and try to implement it. Or maybe get in touch with the project owners to see if they have planned to work on this.

Comment: This is a very common issue with wkhtmltopdf. The underlying problem is that wkhtmltopdf forks a new web browser process that doesn't have the cookies that the logged in user does. You would need to authorize the wkhtmltopdf process using a cookie jar and then use that to render the secure page. Or you could perhaps use php to save the html as a temp file using the current session and then feed that temp page to wkhtmtopdf. If you have any AJAX though, that approach breaks easily. See this and the others next to it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10400278/694325

Answer (score 6):

this is a bit late, but I had the exact same problem, and found a solution for it:
You can pass in options as second parameter in the `getOutput()`-method. One of these options is `cookie`:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
...

$session = $this->get('session');
$session->save();
session_write_close();

return new Response(
    $this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->getOutput(
        $pageUrl,
        array('cookie' => array($session->getName() => $session->getId()))
    ),
    200,
    array(
        'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
    )
);
```

See http://wkhtmltopdf.org/ and https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpSnappyBundle/issues/42 for details.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with that bundle. In my case was the issue that the script was running from the command line. And the problem was that there the executed user was not authenticated in the sonata admin.

So be sure your calling the pdf is logged in user and don't switch between production and development environment that will lost the session and you have to relogin.

So check if the script with is calling the snappy pdf generation is correctly authenticated and has the sonata_admin_role (access to the sonata admin backend).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

2021: I still had the exact same problem but found the accepted solution of Iris Schaffer a little bit dirty. So here is another way. You can just generate the html in the controller you're in.

Instead of using ->getOutput() we use ->getOutputFromHtml()

```
/**
 * @Route("/dossiers/{dossier}/work-order/download", name="download_work_order")
 * @Security("is_granted('DOWNLOAD_WORK_ORDER', dossier)")
 *
 * @param Dossier $dossier
 * @return Response
 */
public function generateWorkOrderPdfAction(Dossier $dossier): Response
{
    /**
     * Since we are a valid logged-in user in this controller we generate everything in advance
     * So wkhtmltopdf does not have login issues
     */
    $html = $this->forward('PlanningBundle\Controller\WorkOrderController::generateWorkOrderHTMLAction', [
        'dossier' => $dossier,
    ])->getContent();

    $options = [
        'footer-html' => $this->renderView('@Dossier/PDF/footer.html.twig', [
            'dossier' => $dossier,
        ]),
    ];

    return new Response(
        $this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->getOutputFromHtml($html, $options),
        200,
        [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
            'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="work-order-' . $dossier->getName() . '.pdf"',
        ]
    );
}
```