# Handling HTML PDFs with Auth Required Images

Tags: html, node.js, authentication, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I'm currently creating pdf documents server side with wkhtmlpdf and nodejs. The client side sends the html to be rendered (which may include img tags with a source). When the user is previewing the html in the browser the images they uploaded to their account show fine because the user is authenticated via the browser and the node route can simply look up the image based on the user id (saved to session) and image id (passed in each image request).

The issue is when the images are attempting to be rendered in wkhtmltopdf webkit the renderer is not authenticated when it makes the request for images via node's exec of wkhtmltopdf in a separate process. A request to something like `GET /user/images/<imageId>` will fail due to the session not being set when the request is made inside the headless wkhtmltopdf renderer.

Is there a way to pass authentication via some wkhtmltopdf option or possibly a different way of authentication for images? The only restriction is not making images public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement authentication I allowed a cookie id flag ( with connect the key defaults to connect.sid ) as a query option in my image routes. The only "gotcha" is since images are requested from the server's perspective, you must ensure all your image paths are absolute domain paths rather than relative to your application ( unless those two are the same of course).

Steps for Expressjs:

1. Setup the id flag middleware which checks for say sid in the query via req.query `(eg ?id=abc123 where abc123 is the req.cookies['connect.sid'], or req.signedCookies['connect.sid'] if your using a secret as you probably should )`You may need to ensure the query middleware is setup first.
2. Ensure the req.headers contains this session id key and value prior to the cookie parser so the session is properly setup `(eg if a cookie exists append a new one or if one does add it as the first req.headers.cookie = 'connect.sid=abc123;')`
3. Ensure all image paths contain the full url `(eg https://www.yourdomain.com/images/imageId?id=abc123)`

Some extra tid bits: The image source replacement should probably happen at the server level to ensure the user does not copy/paste the image url with the session id and say email it to a friend which obviously leaves the door open for account hijacking.

Answer (score 1):

I asked a similar question a while back that might help you:
[Generate PDF Behind Authentication Wall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10287386/generate-pdf-behind-authentication-wall)

WKHTMLTOPDF has `--cookie-jar` which *should* get you what you need. Note that it didn't for me, and I wound up answering my own question with an alternate solution. In a nutshell, I wound up accessing the page via CURL - much more flexible - then writing a temporary that I converted to PDF, then deleted the temporary file.

A little round-a-bout, but it got the job done.

Comment: I'm currently looking at using a url query to append the cookie sid ( the encrypted one) prior to sending the request. I'll post if this ends up working. Thanks for the input.